# How to Approach a Particular Recruiter as a Third-Year Undergraduate

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, internship

I am a third-year undergraduate applying off-campus for a 2021 internship in a particular company.

This company had submitted an INF(Internship Notification Form) to my campus a few months ago, expressing their interest in hiring few interns for a niche tech field(hybrid of two disciplines).

However, I didn't fulfill the branch qualification(they were only accepting students from CSE, Engineering Physics backgrounds) to apply on-campus despite having all other necessary qualifications including the tools and skill sets required.

Not wanting to lose the opportunity, I decided to apply off-campus despite not satisfying their branch requirement (which is pretty common here). I contacted few recruiters of the company via LinkedIn out of which only one replied back and asked me to send him my resume on his email. He said that he would get back to me with the status of my application by the end of the week(which was few weeks ago).

However, since then things have been quiescent from his side. I've dropped an email as well as a message on LinkedIn as a reminder (message was sent 10 days after the email).

I firmly believe that my resume has more to offer than what they were expecting as per their INF and was hoping to get tested/interviewed before being rejected(if at all). I've also been upfront about my excitement to join them since this was a niche field (on hindsight, probably a bad idea since that made me seem desperate).

How do I approach to this recruiter for any response now?

**EDIT**: The recruiter works for the company.

Comment: only if I had his number.

Comment: is a "recruiter" someone who works FOR the company, or, do you mean someone at a "recruitment agency / staffing company" -? thanks for clarifying

Comment: The recruiter works for the company. And on the recommendation of Joe, I'll be trying that route as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though you've already sent enough reminders through various routes, so you may as well consider this lead as cold (much like anyone getting non-responses from recruiters).

All you can really do is approach other recruiters and see if you get any positive response (even if to confirm there are no more openings at this time).

Or you can try contacting the company directly.

Comment: Good to see you back!

Comment: I've thought of doing this as the last resort, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @motosubatsu Just thought the same - winter is slowly settling in and suddenly - Snow!!..;)